# Prevent php from executing code after Javascript validation fails and prevent some characters with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a user registration form and after the user has filled all informations I submit the entered values:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">CheckPassword(document.userform.password);</script>';

        ## connect mysql server
            $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            # check connection
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo "<p>Fehler Nummer {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
                exit();
            }
        ## query database
            # prepare data for insertion
            $username   = $_POST['username'];
            $password   = $_POST['password'];
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
            $email      = $_POST['email'];

            # check if username and email exist else insert
            // u = username, e = emai, ue = both username and email already exists
           //the rest of the code is not important for this question
```

On the first line (`echo '<script...`) I call the following javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckPassword(inputtxt)   
            {   
                var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;  
                if(inputtxt.value.match(passw))   
                {   
                    alert("check");
                    return true;  
                }  
                else{
                    alert("!check");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

The call works perfectly but if the user has entered an invalid password I do not want to run the rest of the php code.

Further I would like to prevent the user to enter special characters, such as: ', ", `, ´,.. How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show us your html code ?

Comment: Your idea is wrong. Use Javascript validation to help user before sending form (block sending if form is incorrect). After form has been send check it again in PHP (this part is most important).

Comment: Your validation must not done by javascript (clientSide) , try to validate the password in php, see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php. If the $_post['password'] match with your regex so you can continue, else show an error...

Comment: Ok I tried it with $searchfor = "/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$/"; if(preg_match($searchfor, $password, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) and it works if the password is correct. but there is no else when the password is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this, you need to move your js validation function to on form submit because php runs server side, while js runs on client side. By the time your js function executes, your php was already been executed on server.

The proper way of doing this is call your function on form submit.

Example:

```
<form name="test_frm" id="test_frm" action="abc.php" onsubmit="return CheckPassword();">
```

Note: this is just an example

Comment: Can I call the php code from the JS function to register the user?

Comment: Yes you can do that by using ajax

Comment: Ok I tried it with `$searchfor = "/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$/"; if(preg_match($searchfor, $password, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))` and it works if the password is correct. but there is no else when the password is incorrect?